# Change nginx proxy_cache_key if particular header present

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to cache ajax request with different proxy_key.

My regular proxy key:

```
 proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri";
```

I want to use different proxy_cache_key for ajax requests (which come with X-Requested-With header).

Something like this

```
if ($http_x_requested_with) {
    proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri$cookie_SID";
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this

First, save `"$host$request_uri"` to a variable with **[set](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#set)**. Then inside `if`, change the variable value. Finally set your `proxy_cache_key` with that custom variable.

**Sidenote**: never use `if` inside location if you don't want get unexpected result. See [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).

Here the example:

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        ...
        set $cache_key "$host$request_uri";

        if ($http_x_requested_with) {
            set $cache_key "$host$request_uri$cookie_SID";
        }

        proxy_cache_key $cache_key;

        location / {
            ....
        }

        location /others {
            .....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks! and it works in location also - don't think that resetting variable with IF can be inappropriate in location statement